# Unable to parse with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date

I am trying to parse the date in a specific pattern but every time it is showing date in only format. Here what I am doing. Output is written in comments in front of the line.

```
String dat = "20-06-2021";

String newFormatLocaleDate = "MMM dd yyyy";
String newFormattedDate = convertToNewFormat(dat,currentFormat,newFormatLocaleDate); //Jun 20 2021
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(newFormatLocaleDate);
LocalDate parse1 = java.time.LocalDate.parse(newFormattedDate,formatter1); //2021-06-20
System.out.println("Using parse1 Pattern Only "+parse1);  //2021-06-20
Date date1 = java.sql.Date.valueOf(parse1);
System.out.println("Using Date Pattern Only "+date1);  //2021-06-20
```

The pattern in which date is required is given and in the string form it giving the correct value but when I am trying to parse it with `LocaleDate` it is changing the format for all dates to the above mentioned `(yyyy-MM-dd)` format irrespective of the newFormatLocaleDate pattern.

Thanks

Comment: What does `convertToNewFormat` do?

Comment: it will take the date which needs to be converted to new format , the current format of the date, the new format of the date in which it is required to be converted . It is working fine and working as per the need.

Comment: "It is working fine and working as per the need" doesn't mean you don't have to post it here. You need a [mcve]. Anyway, it's unclear what the problem is. If you want `MMM dd yyyy` format, can't you just use `newFormattedDate`? Why parse it to another `LocalDate`?

Comment: The line `System.out.println("Using parse1 Pattern Only " + parse1);` will implicitly use `parse1.toString()` which has a fixed (ISO) format. You could define your output format by `parse1.format(formatter1, Locale.ENGLISH);`.

Answer (score 4):

You should not expect the line

```
System.out.println("Using parse1 Pattern Only "+parse1);
```

to output something different than `2021-06-20` it literally is exactly what the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) say what will be out putted.

> The output will be in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd.

So regardless of the format you used while parsing the `LocalDate` value the `toString` method will always output a data in the format `uuuu-MM-dd`.

If you want a different format use the instance method [`format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are printing the `LocalDate` and `Date` instances (using their `toString()` implementation), therefore not formatted according to your desired template. If you want to print out your parsed date in a particular format, you need to apply a formatter again, for example like this:

```
System.out.println(parse1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy")))
```